# is there a way to know if the link to a file is force downloaded?

Tags: php, file, hyperlink, download

the title fully explains my question.
is I have a link to a pdf file, can I know if it is force downloaded link, using php,c++,linux wget command..etc (anything I can use on a server) (not java)

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear.  What do you mean by "force"?

Comment: Maybe follow the link and check the headers?

Comment: http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 0):

Due to the platform-agnostic nature of `HTTP` as a whole, it is impossible to reliably know what method was used to download a file unless the requester voluntarily identified themselves through a user-agent string or something.

If you were to use a web-server language then you can guard the file behind an authentication mechanism.